# SQL: count occurrences of values

Tags: sql, count, group-by

Let

```
user | fruit
------------
1    | apple
1    | apple
1    | apple
2    | apple
2    | apple
1    | pear
```

Trying to combine `count` and `group by` to get

```
user | apples | pears
---------------------
1    | 3      | 1
2    | 2      | 0
```

Any hints on how to proceed are appreciated.

Comment: group by alone will not help you, you will need to pivot your data as well.

Comment: jarlh's answer is exactly the classical way of doing pivot. Works at every sql DBMS incliding ancient ones and it's fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `case` expressions to do conditional counting:

```
select user,
       count(case when fruit = 'apple' then 1 end) as apples,
       count(case when fruit = 'pear' then 1 end) as pears
from tablename
group by user
```

Answer (score 1):

If you´re working on an Oracle, you would use the PIVOT-function:

```
SELECT *
  FROM fruit t
 PIVOT (COUNT(fruit) AS cnt 
          FOR(fruit) IN ('apple' AS apple
                       , 'pear' AS pear) );
```

More details and full samples on PIVOT / UNPIVOT you´ll find in the web (f.e. here https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1 )